# Can any one list the set of fundamental unsolved questions in coordination chemistry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am interested in unsolved problems in coordination chemistry, from particular cases to the most fundamental phenomena.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) If there even are any "fundamental" unsolved questions in chemistry at all is rather debatable. 2) How you define "coordination" chemistry? It's also debatable what is or isn't a coordination compound.

Comment: Hello, Stack Exchange isn't really the right place for open-ended discussion-style questions such as these. There aren't really objective criteria by which one can measure the fundamentalness of a question. There are obviously a lot—possibly even an infinite number!—of unsolved research questions, and whether each of them deserve to be included in a "compilation" of questions cannot be answered easily. In conclusion, there's no "one true right answer" to your question, which is why I've closed it.